# Determine the limit $\lim_{ ( x , y ) \to ( 0 , 0 )} (1 − x ^2 − y^ 2)/( x^ 2 + y ^2)$

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf

Question : Determine whether the limit exists for the following. If so, find their value.

$\lim_{ ( x , y ) \to ( 0 , 0 )} (1 − x ^2 − y^ 2)/( x^ 2 + y ^2)$

Normally we solve this by either cancelling  common terms in numerator and denominator, or by finding the limit along another lines passing through the same common point $(0,0)$. Which gives different limits hence limits won't exist.

This was my approach:

(i)Taking limit along line $y=x$:
$\lim_{ ( x , x ) \to ( 0 , 0 )} (1 − 2x ^2 )/( 2x^ 2)$
Substituting $x=0$, we get limit approaches $\infty$.

(ii) Taking limit along line $x=0$:
$\lim_{ ( 0 , x ) \to ( 0 , 0 )} (1 − y ^2 )/( y^ 2)$
Substituting $y=0$, we get limit approaches $\infty$.

(iii)Taking limit along line $y=0$:
$\lim_{ ( x , 0 ) \to ( 0 , 0 )} (1 − x ^2 )/( x^ 2)$
Substituting $x=0$, we get limit approaches $\infty$.

Hence we observe that the limit exists through any line through the common point $(0,0)$ and that limit tends to $\infty$.

Final conclusion : Limit exist and that limit equals $\infty$.

My doubt is that if we get limit as $\infty$ like this generally, should we rather say that the limit doesn't exist ? (As $\infty$ is not defined).

Is my approach and conclusion correct?

Comment: You can say the limit exists if it tends to infinity always. However your approach is not correct as you have not approached the orgin from all possible ways.Hint: Split the numerator

Comment: You can also use polar coordinates. So you have $\lim_{r\to0^+}\frac 1 {r^2}-1$

Comment: You don’t even need to split the numerator. Just note that, for all possible ways that $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, the numerator tends to $1$, and the denominator is always positive and tends to $0$.

Comment: I've tried splitting to the best of my knowledge, but couldn't cancel. I suppose my understanding is a bit off here. 

Do you mean to do this?
 $\lim_{ ( x , y ) \to ( 0 , 0 )} (1 /( x^ 2 + y ^2) −1)$
and then substitute $(0,0)$ to say that the limit always tends to $infinity$ ?

Comment: Thanks @AdamRubinson, I think I understand now.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a valid way or no, can anyone clarify if it is ok? Since $x$ and $y$ both tend to $0$, we can say that $y$ tends to $x$. Therefore, the given limit is $(1-2x^2)/(2x^2)$ as $x$ tends to $0$, which is the same as lim $1/(2x^2)-1$ as $x$ tends to $0$, clearly the first term tends to infinity, so the original limit tends to infinity as well.